# Openrefine rearange value

Tags: openrefine, grel

In a csv column I have this data:

```
My Dog (101)
ACat(f023.12)
My Dog (101)
ACat ad
```

I like to rearrange them like:

```
101, My Dog ()
f023.12, ACat()
101, My Dog ()
```

To match them I could use a simple regex like `(.* ?)\((.*)\)` (the last row will be kept untouched) https://regex101.com/r/ivrIa3/1

Is there an easier way doing this as:

```
if(value.contains(/(.* ?)\((.*)\)/), value.match(/(.* ?)\((.*)\)/)[1] + ', ' + value.match(/(.* ?)\((.*)\)/)[0], value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenRefine, the easiest way would be to use a facet (like the « Text filter ») to select lines that contains `(…)`.

Then, use the Column command « Edit cells -> Replace ».

Find: `(.*)\s*\((.*)\)`
Replace: `$1, $2`

[image: Dialog for the Replace command.]

Regards,
Antoine